# How fast is too fast?

Tags: animation

Users like apps to be fast. Many apps use animations to "smooth" the experience. If an animations are too slow, the app feels...well, slow. But if the animations are too fast, they may be so fast that they make the app feel "choppy" or appear as if there is no animation at all. So how fast is too fast for animations? How fast can an animation or transition be without looking too choppy or instantaneous?

Comment: Depends on what you are animating, the context it's being used in, the UI, etc. Too many variables here to give you a simple answer.

Comment: should be fast enough to not stop the user from interacting with your application.

Comment: Like DA01 said, it depends on the animation, and the context of its' use. This Material Design documentation of motion may prove useful: [Material Design - Motion](https://material.google.com/motion/material-motion.html#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although mostly you eyeball this, 300ms - 500ms for each animation is nice for standard buttons animations, menu and anything toggled. I will increase the duration if users are not expected to toggle the element frequently, mostly landing at 1s. Timing functions are also something you want to look at as they can make animations look slower or faster.